# vs 2017 npm through package manager console

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, visual-studio-2017, angular-material2

I am trying to manage npm packages through vs 2017 package manage console.

I have installed nodejs on my machine and then running npm commands through package manager console.

The issue that I am facing is
My directory structure is

Project folder level 1

-project folder level 2

- node_modules level 3

-project.sln level 2

Since I am using VS angular template my node_modules are getting created at level 3 by default.

But when I am trying to run any npm command through package manage console its trying to find node_modules at level 2.

Can anyone please guide me how to use npm commands with visual studio solution.

I am trying to create an web app using angular and angular material.

thanks in advance.